# Apache2 100 seconds timeout

Tags: apache-2.2, timeout

I'm running an Apache2 server which redirects (virtualhost) to a tomcat server with a java application.

If I call a big process directly on the tomcat server, it works fine (wget localhost:8080/...).
If I call the same process through the apache server (wget mydomain.com/...), I get a timeout after exactly 100 seconds.

In apache.conf, my timeout setting is 600. So it must be something else which causes this timeout. I have no idea where to look.

The following is the content of mods-enabled:

```
alias.conf       authn_file.load       authz_host.load  autoindex.load  deflate.load  env.load      mime.load         pagespeed.conf  php5.load   proxy_http.load  rewrite.load   status.conf
alias.load       authz_default.load    authz_user.load  cgi.load        dir.conf      expires.load  negotiation.conf  pagespeed.load  proxy.conf  reqtimeout.conf  setenvif.conf  status.load
auth_basic.load  authz_groupfile.load  autoindex.conf   deflate.conf    dir.load      mime.conf     negotiation.load  php5.conf       proxy.load  reqtimeout.load  setenvif.load
```

where/how should I look for this timeout value?

**update: answers to questions below**

- if I do `curl -I mydomain.com`, it just hangs for 100 seconds
- grepping for 100 or 100000 (millisecs) does not give any relevant results
- I'm pretty sure it's 100 seconds, because of the timestamps in `wget mydomain.com`:

  `---2014-09-29 09:41:38 http://...`

  `2014-09-29 09:43:18 ERROR 524: Origin Time-out.`

Comment: Indirect approach, but have you tried just doing `grep -R "100" .` to see all places where 100 exists if you are certain of 100seconds?

Comment: What happens when you do a header check with `curl -I mydomain.com`? Meaning does it hang for 100 seconds there? Or does it redirect to `ocalhost:8080` and then hang?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question here, for future reference (and to help others).

The problem was Cloudflare. Although they don't mention a timeout anywere, disabling the cloudflare service removed the 100 seconds timeout. I will contact CloudFlare and see what they say about this. I will update this answer as soon as I get an answer.

I'm sorry for waisting your time, Grumpy and JakeGould :-s

Comment: any update from Cloudflare?